# Chef: How to use different OS default users based on environment (Vagrant, EC2)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, vagrant, environment

I am writing a cookbook which will be run on Ubuntu. It will create a directory in home of the default user.

```
directory "/home/<default-user>/my-directory" do
  owner <default-user>
end
```

The problem is, this default user is different across environments:

- It is **vagrant** when running on virtual machine using **Vagrant**.
- And it is **ubuntu** when running on **EC2** instance.

What is a good practice to solve this kind of problem? And how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: You should provide more information. What's the "default" user? How is it used in your cookbook? Share some code if possible.

Comment: Hi cbl, I added more information to the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the user an attribute and set that according to your environment.

```
directory "/home/#{node[:my_app][:default_user]}/my-directory" do
  owner node[:my_app][:default_user]
end
```

Then, on your `attributes/default.rb` file:

```
default[:my_app][:default_user] = 'ubuntu'
```

and on your `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    # ...

    chef.json = {
      "my_app" => {
        "default_user" => "vagrant"
      }
    }
  end
end
```

This will set your default user to `ubuntu`, but that will be overridden when running in the Vagrant VM.

Comment: Hey cbl, your solution works nicely for me! Actually I am doing a bit differently by making use of environments: `local` environment where `default_user` is `vagrant`; `ec2` environment where that user is `ubuntu`. And I use `chef.environment` in `Vagrantfile`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, your solution looks good too. I'm glad to help. If you don't mind, please mark my answer as accepted. It both increases my points and helps others who might come to this question to go straight to the working answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the configuration entry `config.ssh.username`: http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/ssh/username.html

Comment: shawnzhu, thank you. That config does not seem to solve the problem since: (1) I set `config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"` but when I ssh into the virtual machine and issue whoami command, I get "vagrant". (2) I am looking for a solution where I can use the same cookbook and the user is still "vagrant" for virtual machine and it is "ubuntu" when running with EC2 instance